# How to hide labels at runtime

Tags: wpf

I have data template which has some labels,what i want to do is to hide some of the labels at runtime depending upon the configuration settings.

I have binded the visibility of the labels to a property but the lables are not hidden even when the property says False.

Below is my xaml

```
<Label x:Name="lblWashingMachineName" Content="{x:Static Resources:Translations.MainWindow_WashingMachineName}"
                            Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource styleLabelBig}" Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowLabels}"></Label>
```

Property

```
    public bool ShowLabels
    {
        get
        {
            return _showLabels;
        }
        private set
        {
            _showLabels = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ShowLabels");
        }
    }
```

Setting the property in constructor

```
    public DisplayScopeRecord()
    {
        ShowLabels = !(AppContext.Instance.DicomizerEnabled);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it my property needs to be of the type Visibility for it to work.

Property

```
    public Visibility ShowLabels
    {
        get
        {
            return _showLabels;
        }
        private set
        {
            _showLabels = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ShowLabels");
        }
    }
```

Constructor

```
    public DisplayScopeRecord()
    {
        if (AppContext.Instance.DicomizerEnabled)
        {
            ShowLabels = Visibility.Hidden;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your variable is a boolean, but Visibility is an enum (Visible, Hidden, Collapsed). You need to convert boolean to visibility with .NET built-in BooleanToVisibilityConverter.

```
<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis" />

<Label x:Name="lblWashingMachineName" Content="{x:Static Resources:Translations.MainWindow_WashingMachineName}"
                        Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource styleLabelBig}" Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowLabels, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"/>
```

Comment: Also, if your ShowLabels property will only be set on the value you've given to it in the  constructor, you could do only with a getter accessor that returns that value.

Answer (score 0):

You should overwrite the style of your Label and set a datatrigger on the value of your **ShowLabels** property.

```xaml
<Label x:Name="lblWashingMachineName" Content="{x:Static Resources:Translations.MainWindow_WashingMachineName}" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="2">
    <Label.Style>
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource styleLabelBig}" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                     <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ShowLabels}" Value="False">
                          <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                     </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
    </Label.Style>
</Label>
```